# Sources for IMO Geometry Theorems

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, circles, congruences-geometry

The International Mathematical Olympiad contains highly non-standard problems involving the geometry of circles, triangles and lines which usually draws upon quite a few theorems and facts not typically covered in any high school curriculum. I know there are books like *Solving Problems in Geometry* by Kim Hoo Hang and *EuclideanGeometry in Mathematical Olympiads* by Evan Chen where such results can be found.

But where are they getting these theorems from? Unfortunately they don't talk about their sources much and I wonder what they might be drawing upon especially since classical geometry courses are pretty much extinct even at university level now. This isn't so much a request for textbook recommendations as it is a request for possible sources of lesser taught theorems of classical geometry.

Any information is much appreciated.

Comment: Why "non-standard"?

Comment: You mean the problems or the theorems? Coming up with those problems is not difficult even for an average Olympiad participant. As for theorems they are usually basic Euclidian Geometry Theorems that you can find in Olympiad preparation resources. Art of Problem Solving (https://artofproblemsolving.com/) is arguably, the most popular platform for math Olympiad kids. You can find all the resources and problems with various solutions.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino I meant theorems

Comment: @ACB I just meant that the problems are usually beyond what would be faced by most high school kids and they also require more theorems to solve that what is contained in almost any high school curriculum.

Comment: Please do not use MathJax for text formatting.